# SmartGWT - how order items into dynamicform?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I try to create a DynamicForm with columns , but I can not order the items into columns . When I put the items in the dynamicForm to exist a column that remain empty .

[Empty column - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aDU.jpg)

this is an extract of code that I use :

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setTitleSuffix("");
form.setIsGroup(true);
form.setGroupTitle("DETALLES DEL PLAN");
form.setWidth(720);
form.setColWidths("150","200","150","200");
form.setNumCols(4);

StaticTextItem planT  = new StaticTextItem("Nombre de Plan: ");
StaticTextItem plan  = new StaticTextItem("PLAN B");

StaticTextItem tipoCartaT = new StaticTextItem("Tipo de Carte:");
tipoCartaT.setStartRow(true);
SelectItem tcSelect = new SelectItem();
tcSelect.setShowTitle(false);
StaticTextItem periodoT = new StaticTextItem("Periodo: ");
SelectItem peSelect = new SelectItem();
peSelect.setShowTitle(false);
peSelect.setEndRow(true);

StaticTextItem descT = new StaticTextItem("Descripcion del Plan");
descT.setStartRow(true);
TextAreaItem deText = new TextAreaItem();
deText.setShowTitle(false);
deText.setStartRow(true);
deText.setColSpan(3);
deText.setWidth(520);

form.setItems(planT,plan,tipoCartaT,tcSelect,periodoT,peSelect,descT,deText);

addMember(form);
```

I try to look like this:

[correct order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KeoT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StaticTextItems are 2 Colums width by default when the title is aligned to the left. So the empty space you are looking at it's the value of planT textItem.

You dont need to use an empty StaticTextItem for titles, you can do it like this.

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setTitleSuffix("");
form.setIsGroup(true);
form.setGroupTitle("DETALLES DEL PLAN");
form.setWidth(720);
form.setColWidths("150","200","150","200");
form.setNumCols(4);

StaticTextItem planT  = new StaticTextItem("Nombre de Plan");
planT.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.LEFT);
planT.setStartRow(true);
planT.setEndRow(true);
planT.setValue("Plan B");

SelectItem tcSelect = new SelectItem("Tipo de Carte");
tcSelect.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.LEFT);
tcSelect.setStartRow(true);

SelectItem peSelect = new SelectItem("Periodo");
peSelect.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.LEFT);
peSelect.setEndRow(true);

TextAreaItem deText = new TextAreaItem("Descripcion del Plan");
deText.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.LEFT);
deText.setStartRow(true);
deText.setEndRow(true);
deText.setColSpan(3);

form.setItems(planT,tcSelect,peSelect,deText);

addMember(form);
```

i hope it helps